# Run process only if no process matching pattern exist - Linux - PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5

I would like to run a process only if there are no matching processes running already. This is what I have:

```
  //get the processes that match artisan queue:work but not ps or grep processes
  exec('ps -ef | grep "[a]rtisan queue:work"', $output);

  //if no process if found start queue worker!
  if(empty($output)) {
      exec('/usr/local/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:work --daemon');
  }
```

When I perform this on a test endpoint on my Laravel application the code works. When I schedule it on Laravel scheduler it creates one process after the other.

After some minutes my machine is filled with these processes running everyminute:

```
user  3128  2722  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:work --daemon
user  6347  6036  0 14:42 ?        00:00:00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:work --daemon
user  9896  9581  0 14:43 ?        00:00:00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:work --daemon
user 14095 13758  0 14:44 ?        00:00:00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:work --daemon
user 17921 17398  0 14:45 ?        00:00:00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:work --daemon
user 31538 30988  0 14:40 ?        00:00:00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:work --daemon
```

Comment: Using a lock file might be a simpler option.

Comment: @JonStirling I found this solution `flock -n /tmp/laravel_queues.lockfile /usr/local/bin/php /home/qwkhirec/laravel-dev/artisan queue:listen` I'm a bit confused still tho, what does the lockfile should contain?

Comment: Will read about it, thanks so much @JonStirling

Comment: It shouldn't contain anything, you only want to check if it exists. Your script would go along the lines of, does this file exists? Yes? Then assume the process is running, No? Then create the file and start processing. Have I finished processing? Yes? Remove the file.